# How do I replace the breadcumbs and replace with the full text path?

Tags: nautilus

How do I remove the breadcumbs and replace with the full text path in the Nautilus address bar by default?

Comment: To whom it may concern, note that **Ctrl-L** does this for the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using 11.10:

1. Install the [dconf-tools[image: Install dconf-tools]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package and then open `dconf-editor`:

   [image]
2. Navigate to *org ➜ gnome ➜ nautilus ➜ preferences*
   and check the *always-use-location-entry* checkbox:

   [image]