# How can I make the file manager toolbar buttons smaller?

Tags: unity, gui

screenshot: 
[image]

I want to make those buttons at the main toolbar smaller because they just don't seem right this way, but how? I'm  using unity.

Answer (score 0):

You can change them by using Unity  tweak tool  or unity tweak tool.  After installing them at tweak tab you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of Nautilus you can make the main toolbar smaller by switching to a location bar viewing but you can't make the icons smaller in bred crumbs view.

You can test if you like this view better by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. This will make the main toolbar look like this:

[image]

These answers will tell you how to make this view permanent:

- [Typing location path instead of clicking directory buttons in the file picker dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13645/typing-location-path-instead-of-clicking-directory-buttons-in-the-file-picker-di)
- [How do I replace the breadcumbs and replace with the full text path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68265/how-do-i-replace-the-breadcumbs-and-replace-with-the-full-text-path)

In recent versions of Nautilus from (> 13.04) the icons are smaller indeed. So in case you feel like upgrading you issue may be solved.

[image]